# Google Maps - Uncaught InvalidValueError: initialise is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I load the page that my Google Maps is displayed, I always see the following error in the console:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: initialise is not a function *js?sensor=false&callback=initialise:94*

When hovering over the filename, this is showing as originating from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialise

The Google Maps window and map displays absolutely fine though and has full functionality. Strangely, I couldn't find any hits on Google regarding this, they all seem to be about setLong and setLat.

If I change the order of loading between the API call, and the JS file, the error message changes between `initialise` and `google`. But in both cases, the map still continues to load fine.

Why is the error occuring, and how do I resolve it properly? Here's my google-map.js file:

```
function initialise() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.126500, 0.257595); // Add the coordinates
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15, // The initial zoom level when your map loads (0-20)
        disableDefaultUI: true, // Disable the map UI
        center: myLatlng, // Centre the Map to our coordinates variable
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // Set the type of Map
        scrollwheel: false, // Disable Mouse Scroll zooming (Essential for responsive sites!)
    // All of the below are set to true by default, so simply remove if set to true:
    panControl:false, // Set to false to disable
    mapTypeControl:false, // Disable Map/Satellite switch
    scaleControl:false, // Set to false to hide scale
    streetViewControl:false, // Set to disable to hide street view
    overviewMapControl:false, // Set to false to remove overview control
    rotateControl:false // Set to false to disable rotate control
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); // Render our map within the empty div
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/wp-content/themes/bellavou/img/marker2.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(70,70)); // Create a variable for our marker image.             
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.125887, 0.258075), // Position marker to coordinates
        icon:image, //use our image as the marker
        map: map, // assign the market to our map variable
        title: 'Bella Vou at The Pantiles' // Marker ALT Text
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise); // Execute our 'initialise' function once the page has loaded.
```

Comment: Without posting your code, how can we possibly help?

Comment: Not sure that you need it, but okay I will post it...

Comment: First, you define a callback on the API call `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialise` then you add a listener `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);` that basically does the same. Remove that listener line or remove the `callback=initialise` from the API call and let us know if it works better.

Comment: Yep, I removed the `callback=initialise` from the API call, and the error has removed. Thank you for that, add as an answer when you're ready!

Comment: Cool that it works. You are welcome!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, you define a callback on the API call:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialise`

then you add a listener

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);`

that basically does the same.

---

You should **remove** the `callback=initialise` from the API call **or** the above mentioned `addDomListener` line from your JS file and it should work.